# Modify the popup in chrome extension once iframe is loaded inside it

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to modify the popup.html of the chrome extension. I load an iFrame containing an external URL inside it. Once the iFrame is loaded, I want to modify the div tag in popup.html

**popup.html**

```
<head>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form name = "getPage" action = "http://website.com/" method = "post" target = "post_stuff">
        <input type = "hidden" name = "hdnrequesttype" value = "1" />
        <input type = "hidden" name = "txtmemberid" id = "txtmemberid" value = "11012333" />
        <input type = "hidden" name = "txtmemberpwd" id = "txtmemberpwd" value = "" />
        <input type = "hidden" name = "sites" value = "0" />
        <input type = "hidden" name = "firsttime" value = "Y" />
    </form>
    <iframe name = "post_stuff" height = "600" width = "600" onload = "frame_loaded()">
    </iframe>
    <div id = "putText">
    </div>
</body>
```

**popup.js**

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.forms["getPage"].submit();
}

function frame_loaded() {
    document.getElementById("putText").innerHTML = "LOADED";
    console.log("LOADED");
}
```

This did not work. I tried using a content script, but that did not work too. The contents of my content script, modify.js:-

**modify.js**

```
document.getElementById("putText").innerHTML = "LOADED";
```

Here is the relevant section of my manifest:-

```
"content_scripts" : [ {
                            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
                            "js": ["modify.js"]
                       }
                    ]
```

I hope that someone can help me with this.

Comment: Are you using `manifest_version: 2`? Your inline `onload` handler is not allowed under version 2.

Comment: I am using manifest_version:2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using `manifest_version: 2`. If so, you'll need to use `addEventListener` instead of your inline `onload` handler:

```
window.onload = function() {
    //attach a load listener to the iframe
    document.querySelector("iframe").addEventListener("load", frame_loaded);
    document.forms["getPage"].submit();
}
```